# How to use curl to generate http 1.0 request for a file without a leading slash?

Tags: curl

Below is the request I received from server log. I am worried this may trigger some crash. The server is a simple express dev server.

```
"GET login.cgi HTTP/1.0"
```

How do I use curl to duplicate the above exact request?

- no path
- login.cgi
- HTTP 1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

Not even a leading slash? That's not likely to ever get sent by any HTTP clients.

If you can do with a slash, you can do it with:

`curl --http1.0 localhost/login.cgi`

If you **really** insist on not having a leading slash in there, you need to get yourself curl 7.55.0 (or later) and use the [--request-target](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--request-target) option to override the request target manually, like this:

`curl --http1.0 localhost --request-target login.cgi`

(and of course you should replace 'localhost' with the host name of your choice)

### Without curl

A cruder approach to do the same request is to craft it with printf + nc, like this:

```
printf "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80
```

.... where you of course need to add the set of headers you want to pass on yourself. The `Host:` there is just an example showing how to do it.

Comment: Is there other low level tool can do "--request-target"?